# Organize objects in an array depending on their property?

Tags: arrays, swift, ios8

How can I organize an array of objects depending on their property? For example lets say if I have this:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

struct Person {

    let name : String!
    let age : Int!
    let charcter : characterType!

    enum characterType {
        case happy, sad, mad, scared, excited
    }
}

let people : [Person] = [

    Person(name: "Bob", age: 10, charcter: Person.characterType.happy),
    Person(name: "Joe", age: 45, charcter: Person.characterType.sad),
    Person(name: "Tom", age: 105, charcter: Person.characterType.scared),
    Person(name: "Mad", age: 3, charcter: Person.characterType.mad)

]
```

How can I organize the `people` array depending on their `character type`?
I want all the people that are mad to be first, then happy, then sad, then scared in a new array.

How can I do this? `var newArray : [Person] ...`

Also one more thing I have already tried the following:

```
   func organizeArray(){

    var newArray = [Person]()

    var array1 = []
    var array2 = []
    var array3 = []
    var array4 = []
    var array5 = []

    for person in people {
        switch person.charcter {
            case happy...
                append to array 1
            case mad...
            append to array 2

so on...

        }

    }
    newArray = array1 + array2 + array3 + array4 + array5
}
```

But when I run this it takes XCode forever to index. If I remove this function everyting works fine. I want a solution that is simple, and won't cause XCode to index forever (alot).

Comment: does it really cause "Xcode to index forever"? I doubt… I susepct it's rather **your code** that gets into an infinite loop and this has actually *nothing* to do with Xcode (since it's just the editor, it isn't your code.) As to how to **sort** your array: use its `sort` method and pass in a comparator closure that compares two objects using whichever property you need.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant alot i mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What are you doing is to create a separate array for every character type and then join them together. This is not efficient. As suggested by [the-paramagnetic-croissant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3477950/the-paramagnetic-croissant) you should use the sort functionality of the swift array combined with the possibility of associating a raw value to an enumeration type in this way:

```
struct Person {
    let name : String
    let age : Int
    let charcter : characterType

    enum characterType: Int {
       case mad = 0, happy, sad, scared, excited
   }
}

let people : [Person] = [
    Person(name: "Bob", age: 10, charcter: Person.characterType.happy),
    Person(name: "Joe", age: 45, charcter: Person.characterType.sad),
    Person(name: "Tom", age: 105, charcter: Person.characterType.scared),
    Person(name: "Mad", age: 3, charcter: Person.characterType.mad) 
]

let newArray = people.sorted { $0.charcter.rawValue < $1.charcter.rawValue }

println(newArray[0].charcter.rawValue) // Mad
println(newArray[1].charcter.rawValue) // Happy
println(newArray[2].charcter.rawValue) // Sad
println(newArray[3].charcter.rawValue) // Scared
```